# Reopen Request: Work/Life Balance in Accounting Field

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[Work/Life Balance in Accounting Field](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/98724/62397)

I believe I have edited this question substantially from its original version.  It no longer asks multiple questions, and should be much clearer.  Might this be reopened?

My extended discussions in the comments have suggested that the question is very answerable. I believe that some people may consider certain answers to this issue to be obvious, but I've found them non-trivial and enlightening, and hope they can be elaborated upon.

Comment: That question is still really broad IMHO.  Let's see what others think.

Comment: @MisterPositive Do you have any further advice on how to improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that can be answered, to be honest.

> Are the average number of hours worked in the Accounting and Finance fields higher than other fields?

It's higher than some jobs. But that's not the question you are really asking - you *probably* don't care that an Accountant works more hours than a fast food employee on average, do you?

> He has adopted a sort of fatalism, resigning himself to a life of misery that will be ongoing until retirement.

He needs a counselor (or doctor, potentially). There's really not much a bunch of folks on the internet can help with here in my opinion.

Most of the question is more counseling than "answers" and meaningful advice seems like it'd need much more detail about your friend's seeming state of depression rather than objective facts regarding their outlook.

Comment: Depression is a real possibility, but I don't have much faith in getting him to a councilor.  I'm trying to find the best solution that I can help with personally through advice.

Comment: "I'm 100% positive it's higher than most jobs" - I think that is demonstrably true. Yet, I'm also 100% positive that there are many, many jobs where the employee works more hours than most jobs (and often more hours than accountants). But as always, it depends. You don't apply for "the average", you apply for one specific job. And that job could require any number of hours from very few to quite a lot.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I guess without clarification, I was including all employees. Perhaps the OP meant "salaried employees" when they said it?

Comment: @enderland - I understood where you were going. It's not clear what the OP meant. I disagree with the implied notion that accountants inevitably work far more hours than almost everyone else. I know plenty of accountants that seldom if ever work more than 40 hours. And I know plenty of non-accountants that work far more than 40 (That doctor you mention probably does. I did.) There are *lots* of accountants in the world. They aren't all doing the same thing.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere ahh, good point. I edited that statement as it wasn't really necessary to the point of what I had here anyways.